# scrollview in android using layout Inflater

Tags: android, scrollview, layout-inflater

Below is a mainActivity code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_show);

        tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
        tableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++) {
          //Rows will add till condition is true
        }
    }
```

XML FILE : layout_show

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >It has eight headers for eight columns in it

</TableLayout>
```

XML to be scrolled table_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <TableRow 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/table1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp" 
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:background="@color/LightPink">---Columns defined here----  
   </TableRow>
```

All works fine

1. Data of single row in different columns is taken from different source.
2. Using `ScrollView` in `table_item.xm`l is not working but disturbing the alignment from header and item columns.

The result to be achieved is:

1. Keep the header but scroll the inflated rows of the `table_item.xml`

Hope i get some clue...

Thanks for the time

Comment: I did not understand what's the exact problem here. Can you please state your question clearly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vesko.. When count of the for loop goes beyond 12 the other rows added after 12, cannot be seen unless screen is larger, so scrolling to up(vertical) is needed; but i am not able to achieve the results desired.

Answer (score 0):

`TableLayout` is not a scrollable container itself, thus the behavior you're describing is normal. Easiest solution for you would be to wrap the `TableLayout` with a `ScrollView`. You can do this in your `layout_show.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks Vesko tried that ScrollView both programmatically and in xml separately and together but didn't work. After trying the other possible ways, decided to go with writing the the adapter.java class to convert the view. But would like this way if work. Obviously because it is easier way